# What is the fastest way to parallelize the retrieval of 60 rows, where each row resides in a different partition from Azure Table Storage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure-table-storage

What is the fastest way to parallelize the retrieval of 60 rows, where each row resides in a different partition from Azure Table Storage?

I have tried the following options, where the asynchronous calls (no. 1 - 4) all took approximately similar times of 2 - 3 seconds to get the 60 rows.

1. Using multiple tasks with asynchronous Query.Execute
2. Using one ManualResetEvent with Interlocked.Increment and asynchronous Query.Execute
3. Using a List of ManualResetEvents with asynchronous Query.Execute
4. Parallel.ForEach loop with a List of ManualResetEvents and using asynchronous Query.Execute
5. Parallel.ForEach with a Blocking Query.Execute

FYI, I am using Azure SDK 1.7, and .Net 4.

Sample code that I am using for each option:

1. Using multiple tasks with asynchronous Query.Execute

   ```
   public List<string> Get100RowsUsingTaskWaitAllWithAsyncExecute()
   {
       var result = new ConcurrentBag<LogEntry>();

       var tasks = new Queue<Task>();

       foreach (var eachId in _rowKeysToGet.Take(60))
       {
           var cloudStorageAccount =
               CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingConnectionString"]);
           var ctx = new LogServiceContext(
               cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri,
               cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);

           var query = (from e in ctx.LogEntries where e.RowKey == eachId
                            && e.PartitionKey == _partitionKey
                        select e).AsTableServiceQuery<LogEntry>();

           tasks.Enqueue(
               Task<ResultSegment<LogEntry>>.Factory.FromAsync(
                   query.BeginExecuteSegmented,
                   query.EndExecuteSegmented,
                   TaskCreationOptions.None)
               .ContinueWith(t => {
                   var r = t.Result.Results.FirstOrDefault();
                   result.Add(r);
               }));
       }

       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

       var output = result.Select(r => r.RowKey).ToList();

       return output;
   }
   ```
2. Using one ManualResetEvent with Interlocked.Increment and asynchronous Query.Execute

   ```
   public List<string> Get100RowsUsingOneManualResetEventWithAsyncExecute()
   {
       var result = new ConcurrentBag<LogEntry>();

       var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingConnectionString"]);
       var ctx = new LogServiceContext(cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);

       var threadCount = 0;
       using (var finished = new ManualResetEvent(false))
       {
           foreach (var eachId in _rowKeysToGet.Take(60))
           {
               Interlocked.Increment(ref threadCount);

               var query = (from e in ctx.LogEntries
                            where e.RowKey == eachId
                                  && e.PartitionKey == _partitionKey
                            select e).AsTableServiceQuery<LogEntry>();

               var startTimeInLoop = DateTime.UtcNow;

               query.BeginExecuteSegmented((ar) =>
               {
                   var response = (ar.AsyncState as CloudTableQuery<LogEntry>)
                       .EndExecuteSegmented(ar);

                   var eachLogEntry = response.Results.FirstOrDefault();

                   result.Add(eachLogEntry);

                   if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount) == 0)
                   {
                       finished.Set();
                   }

               }, query);
           }

           finished.WaitOne();
       }

       return result.Select(r => r.RowKey).ToList();
   }
   ```
3. Using a List of ManualResetEvents with asynchronous Query.Execute

   ```
   public List<string> Get100RowsUsingListOfManualResetEventsWithAsyncExecute()    
   {
       var result = new ConcurrentBag<LogEntry>();

       var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingConnectionString"]);
       var ctx = new LogServiceContext(cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);

       var events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

       foreach (var eachId in _rowKeysToGet.Take(60))
       {
           var query = (from e in ctx.LogEntries
                        where e.RowKey == eachId
                            && e.PartitionKey == _partitionKey
                        select e).AsTableServiceQuery<LogEntry>();

           var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

           LogEntry eachLogEntry = null;
           query.BeginExecuteSegmented((ar) => {
               var response = (ar.AsyncState as CloudTableQuery<LogEntry>)
                   .EndExecuteSegmented(ar);

               eachLogEntry = response.Results.FirstOrDefault();

               result.Add(eachLogEntry);

               evt.Set();

           }, query);

           events.Add(evt);
       };

       WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());

       events.ForEach(e => e.Dispose());

       return result.Select(r => r.RowKey).ToList();
   }
   ```
4. Parallel.ForEach loop with a List of ManualResetEvents and using asynchronous Query.Execute

   ```
   public List<string> Get100RowsUsingParallelForEachAndManualResetEventWithAsyncExecute()
   {
       var result = new ConcurrentBag<LogEntry>();

       var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingConnectionString"]);
       var ctx = new LogServiceContext(cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);

       var events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

       Parallel.ForEach(_rowKeysToGet.Take(60), eachId =>
       {
           var query = (from e in ctx.LogEntries
                         where e.RowKey == eachId
                             && e.PartitionKey == _partitionKey
                         select e).AsTableServiceQuery<LogEntry>();

           var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

           LogEntry eachLogEntry = null;
           query.BeginExecuteSegmented((ar) =>
           {
               var response = (ar.AsyncState as CloudTableQuery<LogEntry>)
                   .EndExecuteSegmented(ar);

               eachLogEntry = response.Results.FirstOrDefault();

               result.Add(eachLogEntry);

               evt.Set();

           }, query);

           events.Add(evt);
       });

       WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());

       events.ForEach(e => e.Dispose());

       return result.Select(r => r.RowKey).ToList();
   }
   ```
5. Parallel.ForEach with a Blocking Query.Execute

   ```
   public List<string> Get100RowsUsingParallelForEachWithBlockingExecute()
   {
       var result = new ConcurrentBag<LogEntry>();

       var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingConnectionString"]);
       var ctx = new LogServiceContext(cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);

       Parallel.ForEach(_rowKeysToGet.Take(60), eachId =>
       {
           var query = (from e in ctx.LogEntries
                        where e.RowKey == eachId
                            && e.PartitionKey == _partitionKey
                        select e).AsTableServiceQuery<LogEntry>();

           var eachLogEntry = query.Execute().FirstOrDefault();

           result.Add(eachLogEntry);
       });

       return result.Select(r => r.RowKey).ToList();
   }
   ```